# How to check if value in input array in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I have a pure SQL function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_buildings_by_type(
    building_types TEXT
)

RETURNS TABLE (bldg_id TEXT, "SurfArea" FLOAT, geom GEOMETRY) AS

$$
    SELECT
        bldg."OBJECTID"::TEXT AS bldg_id,
        bldg."SurfArea"::FLOAT,
        bldg.geom
    FROM
        static.buildings AS bldg
    WHERE
        bldg."LandUse" = $1
$$

LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And it behaves as expected, everything is working. However, I would like to have it work with an input array of `building_types`, rather than a single values. When I try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_buildings_by_type(
    building_types TEXT[]
)

RETURNS TABLE (bldg_id TEXT, "SurfArea" FLOAT, geom GEOMETRY) AS

$$
    SELECT
        bldg."OBJECTID"::TEXT AS bldg_id,
        bldg."SurfArea"::FLOAT,
        bldg.geom
    FROM
        static.buildings AS bldg
    WHERE
        bldg."LandUse" IN $1
$$

LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 15:   bldg."LandUse" IN $1
```

Any ideas?

The version is 9.6 if that is relevant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Still the same syntax error. I put the version in too since it might matter.

Comment: `in` operator is not for arrays, @a_horse_with_no_name posted the correct answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name answer is indeed correct, I think I was executing in the wrong window before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of an `IN` operator for arrays is the `any` operator:

You need to use:

```
WHERE
    bldg."LandUse" = any($1);
```